# Git not updating remote repository on push - I know I'm doing it wrong, but can't figure out what

Tags: git

I am sure I'm doing something very basic wrong, but I have searched other answers here and still can't get it right.
My OS is Ubuntu 18.04 LTS.
I cannot get a `git push` to update changed files in the original repository from a clone.

I've set up a very basic configuration of GIT for me to learn with.  In my home directory, I create a directory `gittest`, I then create a simple `test.txt` file in that directory, do `git init`, then `git add` and `git commit`.  So far so good.

I then create a directory `$HOME/work`, then in that directory do a `git pull $HOME/gittest`.  Again, all good, the `gittest` directory is created, and the `test.txt` file is there.

In the `$HOME/work/gittest` directory, I did `git checkout master` just in case, but it reported I was already on the master.

I then change the `test.txt` file in `$HOME/work/gittest`.  `git status` shows it is modified, so I do `git commit -a -m "testing"`, which all seems to be ok.

`git status` in `$HOME/work/gittest` now says I'm ahead of `origin/master` by 1 commit.  Again, all good as that is expected.

I then do `git push origin master` in the directory `$HOME/work/gittest` - it reports things changed, and now `git status` says I'm up to date with `origin master`.

When I go back to `$HOME/gittest`, `test.txt` has not been changed to match the `test.txt` file in `$HOME/work/gittest`.  If I do `git status`, however, it shows `test.txt` has an uncommitted change.  `git diff` shows no differences however.  `git commit -a -m "testing 2"` does the commit, but `test.txt` is still not changed.

I've pulled my hair out all day long trying to get this simple process to work, any help will be appreciated.

```
Ubuntu1804:~$ mkdir gittest

Ubuntu1804:~$ cd gittest

Ubuntu1804:~/gittest$ pico test.txt

Ubuntu1804:~/gittest$ cat test.txt


testing git


Ubuntu1804:~/gittest$ git init
Initialized empty Git repository in /home/marksires/gittest/.git/

Ubuntu1804:~/gittest$ git status
On branch master

Initial commit

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

        test.txt

nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)

Ubuntu1804:~/gittest$ git add test.txt

Ubuntu1804:~/gittest$ git status
On branch master

Initial commit

Changes to be committed:
  (use "git rm --cached <file>..." to unstage)

        new file:   test.txt


Ubuntu1804:~/gittest$ git commit -a -m "test 1"
[master (root-commit) dfe13e2] test 1
 1 file changed, 2 insertions(+)
 create mode 100644 test.txt

Ubuntu1804:~/gittest$ git status
On branch master
nothing to commit, working directory clean

Ubuntu1804:~/gittest$ cd ..

Ubuntu1804:~$ mkdir work

Ubuntu1804:~$ cd work

Ubuntu1804:~/work$ git clone $HOME/gittest
Cloning into 'gittest'...
done.

Ubuntu1804:~/work$ ls
gittest

Ubuntu1804:~/work$ ls gittest
test.txt

Ubuntu1804:~/work$ cd gittest

Ubuntu1804:~/work/gittest$ git status
On branch master
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.
nothing to commit, working directory clean

Ubuntu1804:~/work/gittest$ git checkout master
Already on 'master'
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.

Ubuntu1804:~/work/gittest$ pico test.txt

Ubuntu1804::~/work/gittest$ cat test.txt

testing git

line 2 for testing


Ubuntu1804:~/work/gittest$ git status
On branch master
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.
Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

        modified:   test.txt

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")

Ubuntu1804:~/work/gittest$ git commit -a -m "testing 2"
[master 51ddc40] testing 2
 1 file changed, 2 insertions(+)

Ubuntu1804:~/work/gittest$ git status
On branch master
Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 1 commit.
  (use "git push" to publish your local commits)
nothing to commit, working directory clean

Ubuntu1804:~/work/gittest$ git push origin master
Counting objects: 3, done.
Writing objects: 100% (3/3), 277 bytes | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 3 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
To /home/marksires/gittest
   dfe13e2..51ddc40  master -> master

Ubuntu1804:~/work/gittest$ cd $HOME/gittest

Ubuntu1804:~/gittest$ ls
test.txt

Ubuntu1804:~/gittest$ git status
On branch master
Changes to be committed:
  (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)

        modified:   test.txt


Ubuntu1804:~/gittest$ git diff test.txt

Ubuntu1804:~/gittest$ cat test.txt

testing git


Ubuntu1804:~/gittest$ cat $HOME/work/gittest/test.txt

testing git

line 2 for testing
```

Comment: Hi, not quite sure what you trying to do. What do you get if you do `git remote -v` in both directories.They should both point to the same github remote

Comment: in $HOME/gittest (the 'master' repository), git remote -v returns nothing

Comment: in $HOME/work/gittest (the 'remote' repository) git remote -v return $HOME/gittest for both fetch and push

Comment: What I am trying to do is set up a 'master repository' ($HOME/gittest), put a file in it, initialize git there.  Then set up a 'remote' or 'working' repository ($HOME/work/gittest) by cloning $HOME/gittest, change the file that was pulled, commit the change, then push that change back to the master ($HOME/gittest).  It all works except the push back to $HOME/gittest

Comment: Yep, that sounds about right. Seems like everything you doing is locally, which tells me you are missing a very important step. After you `init` your first repository, you should create a repository in one of the version control platforms such as github.com. Just go to github.com, create a repository and follow the steps after creation. Once that is done, you can clone the repository to any directory you want and things should work

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to push to a non-bare repository. When I reproduce your steps, the git push command gets rejected:

```
$ git push origin master
Enumerating objects: 5, done.
Counting objects: 100% (5/5), done.
Writing objects: 100% (3/3), 254 bytes | 254.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 3 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: error: refusing to update checked out branch: refs/heads/master
remote: error: By default, updating the current branch in a non-bare repository
remote: is denied, because it will make the index and work tree inconsistent
remote: with what you pushed, and will require 'git reset --hard' to match
remote: the work tree to HEAD.
remote: 
remote: You can set the 'receive.denyCurrentBranch' configuration variable
remote: to 'ignore' or 'warn' in the remote repository to allow pushing into
remote: its current branch; however, this is not recommended unless you
remote: arranged to update its work tree to match what you pushed in some
remote: other way.
remote: 
remote: To squelch this message and still keep the default behaviour, set
remote: 'receive.denyCurrentBranch' configuration variable to 'refuse'.
To /tmp/gittest
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (branch is currently checked out)
error: failed to push some refs to '/tmp/gittest'
```

In your case, you might try `git reset --hard` in the first repository, as suggested above.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer.  As I suspected, it was just a 'newbie' issue of not understanding git.  The 'pushed' file(s) are not modified in the 'master' repository by the push, so looking at them directly in $HOME/gittest still shows the original file.  If I create another remote directory by cloning $HOME/gittest to $HOME/work2/gittest, the file pulled from $HOME/gittest reflects the changes that were pushed from $HOME/work/gittest to $HOME/gittest.  I'm sure there is a way to see the 'current' version of the file directly in $HOME/gittest, since gitlab and github do that. I haven't found it yet and for my current exercises it is not needed.  Knowing that a pull will alway reflect the current state with all pushes from remote is sufficient.
Thanks for all the other answers, some good information in them also!